# Update Namespace Module Variables from external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, resize

I'll try and keep this super simple and just use an outline of the code I currently have. Essentially I have a namespace module that is a self-invoking function, it runs on load and populates the variables with their values and returns them to make them accessible to other functions:

```
moduleA = function() {
    var a = $(window).height(),
        b = $('#imgs').height(),
    // other variables that need updating

    return {
       windowH: a,
       imgH: b
    }
}();
```

These variables are then accessed inside another function that is called on scroll:

```
function scrollSpeed() {
    var start = $('#article-wrap').offset().top,
        end = (start + moduleA.imgH) - moduleA.windowH;

    //use variables in animations
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollSpeed();
})
```

The problem with the above is when I resize the window I need to update the variables inside moduleA. Initially I wrote a function "update()" inside the module and returned it, this was then called inside my debounced resize function, but this isn't working?

```
moduleA = function() {
    var a = $(window).height(),
        b = $('#imgs').height(),
    // other variables that need updating

    function update() {
       a = $(window).height(),
       b = $('#imgs').height(),
       ...// other variables that are updated
    }

    return {
       windowH: a,
       imgH: b,
       update: update
    }
}();

var resizeFn = debounce(function() {
    moduleA.update();
}, 100);
```

Obviously I've not included everything here, I can upon request. Any ideas where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your object properties aswell:

```
function update() {
   a = $(window).height(),
   b = $('#imgs').height(),
   ...// other variables that are updated

   this.windowH = a;
   this.imgH = b;
}
```